# How to verify a function $||\cdot||_d$ is a norm over the set of continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $a < b$ and let $C([a, b])$ denote the set of continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Define the function $||\cdot||_n: C([a, b]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $n \ge 1$

$$||f||_n = \left[ \int_a^b[f(t)]^n dt \right] ^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I want to show that this function is indeed a norm over $C([a, b])$. The non-negative and scalar multiplication conditions are trivial to show. So what remains is to prove the triangle inequality. I've tried converting the above integral into a Reimann sum and applying the amgm inequality to no avail.

Comment: You will need [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: Thank you this wikipedia page contains everything I need